# How to update state without passing it to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a little bit simplified example of my current React.js code.

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/14668/

```
var Main = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            showText: false
        }
    },
    handleClick: function(){
        this.setState({
            showText: true
        })
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Press me</button>
                <Child showText={this.state.showText} />
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        if(this.props.showText){
            return (
                <div>
                    Pressed
                </div>
            )
        }
        return (
            <div>
                Default text
            </div>
        )
    }
});

React.render(<Main/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

When I change my `showText` property to true and pass it down to my child component, how can I immediately switch my `showText` to false?

What I would want is something like this except that callback shouldn't be sent to child.

```
handleClick: function(){
    this.setState({
        showText: true
    }, function(){
        showText: false
    })
}
```

My `Main` component should only send true's to child when button is pressed.  Otherwise I want it's state to be false all the time.

Comment: Do you want to flip the value of `showText` on Main back to false without causing the prop change in Child?

So basically the Child will only ever go from 'Default text' to 'Pressed' and never back to 'Default text'?

If this is the case why do you need to set `showText` back to false?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from your description, then this is maybe what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/4vL3mubf/2/

The Child component will never change after the first click but that's what I assumed you wanted.

Basically the Main component can flip the state with this function:

```
componentDidUpdate: function(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.showText === true) {
        this.setState({showText: false});
    }
},
```

**Update**

Updated fiddle with Jim's usage of `shouldComponentUpdate`.
https://jsfiddle.net/4vL3mubf/3/

Comment: I want `showText` to be false after it's sent to child as a true. When it's turned to false, it should not re-render child anymore. And this is problematic, because `setState()` will always re-render. Workflow should be like this: `showText:false` -> user presses button -> `showText:true` -> "Pressed" text appears in child -> `showText` updates to false, but doesn't anymore send it to child.

Comment: See my jsfiddle - whilst it will still send the showText to the Child as a prop (don't think there's anyway of avoiding that), the child will ignore the value if the prop value is false.  Jim's use of shouldComponentUpdate on the child is probably a better solution to mine as it means the child is not maintaining state.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setState` on your parent component will cause the `render` function to fire, which in turn will re-render your `Child` component also.  You should only ever need to `setState` on your parent and the rest of the hierarchy should re-render according to that parent state.

Answer (score 0):

```
var updating = false;

var Main = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            showText: false
        }
    },
    handleClick: function(){
        updating = !updating;
        alert('is updating: ' + updating);
        if(updating) {
            this.setState({
                showText: true
            });
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Press me</button>
                <Child showText={this.state.showText} />
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

or another way:

```
var Child = React.createClass({
    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
        return nextProps.showText;
    },
    render: function(){
        if(this.props.showText){
            return (
                <div>
                    Pressed
                </div>
            )
        }
        return (
            <div>
                Default text
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/14670/